# Harbour on DOS with DJGPP undefined refrence to "main()" and undefined reference to `hb_vmEx ecute'

Tags: gcc, linker, dos

I have installed Harbour 1.0.1 on MSOS 6.22
I am using djgpp. When I tried to build exe it gves following errors

```
C:\HB101\TEST>BLD TESTPRG                                                       
c:/djgpp/lib/crt0.o:crt0.s:(.data+0xc2): undefined reference to `main'          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `hb_vmProcessSymbolsEx'                                                                 
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `hb_vmExecute'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `hb_vmExecute'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `hb_vmExecute'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `hb_vmExecute'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `hb_vmExecute'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o:TESTPRG.c:(.text+0x1dc): more undefined references to `hb_vmExecute' follow                                                             
c:/djgpp/bin/ld.exe: c:/djgpp/tmp/ccpmwnoY.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'                                                                          
c:/djgpp/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation                       
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have got all required lib files, Then Why it is giving this error ?

Comment: What does the `BLD` command do? How does it run `gcc`?

Comment: bld.bat is the batch file supplied by Harbour developers which compiles programs as per the compiler you choose It can use gcc/ BCC/MSVC/ It starts the build process with all required libraries and command line options appropriate for each compiler

Comment: It's apparently not working.